# Sails.create even when item is null?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js

I've got a function which pulls a huge object of data, and loops through each array as `item`.

Within that function, I am using `model.create` to save various items in the array to my database, for example:

```
model.create({
    name: item.name,
    rating: item.rating.average,
    imageMedium: item.image.medium,
    imageLarge: item.image.large
)}, function(err, res) {};
```

Everything works great, if `name` doesn't exist, it's null, and the same goes for anything else.  The problem I am facing though is that if `item.image` is null, I then get a TypeError saying it cannot read medium/large of null.
The entire create for that array is then errored and no data at all is created in my database for that array.

Is there anyway that if in the example above, item.image doesn't exist, it just uses null instead of erroring out?

Comment: When/how is `item` being created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is example:

```
model.create({
   name: item.name,
   rating: item.rating.average,
   imageMedium: !item.image?null:item.image.medium,
   imageLarge: !item.image?null:item.image.large
)}, function(err, res) {};
```

Comment: Ah!  I wasn't aware I could put an if statement inside the array I am sending to create.  No idea why that didn't cross my mind! Will try now.